How to use the cloudflare worker cache as a fast KV?
I cant seem to get the Cloudflare cache working as described in the Cloudflare documentation https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/cache/
I am trying to use Cloudflare worker cache as a caching layer in front of my database.
const CACHE_URL_PREFIX = 'https://api.example.com/';

function getCache() {
  return caches.default;
}

function generateHash(str: string) {
  let hash = 0, i, chr;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    chr = str.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
    hash |= 0;
  }
  return hash.toString(36);
}

function toUniqueUrlPath(str: string) {
  let normalizedStr = str.trim();

  normalizedStr = normalizedStr.toLowerCase();
  
  normalizedStr = normalizedStr.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '-');
  normalizedStr = normalizedStr.replace(/\s+/g, '-'); 

  const uniqueHash = generateHash(str);

  return `${normalizedStr}-${uniqueHash}`;
}

export function getCacheKey(key: string) {
  const normalizedKey = toUniqueUrlPath(key);

  const url = (CACHE_URL_PREFIX + normalizedKey)
    .replace(/\/+/g, '/');

  return new Request(url);
}

export async function getCacheValue<T>(key: string) {
  const cache = await getCache();
  const cacheKey = getCacheKey(key);
  
  const cachedResponse = await cache.match(cacheKey);
  
  if (cachedResponse) {
    return await cachedResponse.json() as T;
  }

  return undefined;
}


export async function setCacheValue<T>(key: string, value: T, ttl: number) {
  const cache = await getCache();
  const cacheKey = getCacheKey(key);

  const response = new Response(JSON.stringify(value), {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cache-Control': `public, max-age=${ttl}`
    }
  });

  await cache.put(cacheKey, response);

  const valueFromCache = await getCacheValue<T>(key); 

  if (!valueFromCache) {
    console.error('Failed to set cache value', {
      key,
      value,
      ttl,
      url: cacheKey.url,
    });
  }
}

The console error "Failed to set cache value" keeps being hit and on subsequent requests the getCacheValue isn't returning anything. I have been trying to debug this for the past 3 hours.
Is there anything wrong with my implementation?

Update. I had something a caching rule in Website / caching / caching-rules that applied to the worker cache. Deleted the rule now it works fine.
